# How do I get an Android application's method to run a method daily with Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I am trying to make my Android app run a method once daily using SharedPreferences. Here is the code of what I have thus far..

```
    //for onEntry ad to run once daily
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    int lastDayRan;
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
              "com.example.myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(prefs.getInt("lastDayRan", lastDayRan) != today){//what to do now?

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make sure at least one day has passed since the last time you ran the desired method, do:

```
long minStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000*60*60*24;
long lastTimeRan = prefs.getLong("lastTimeRan", -1);
if (lastTimeRan >= minStartTime) {
        // a day passed. do whatever...
        //also save the new 'lastTimeRan' in prefs
        prefs.edit().putLong("lastTimeRan", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
}
```

and it would be nice if instead of wring "lastTimeRan", you would use a const

Comment: Just saw my answer after a while. It is better to now use apply() instead of commit() since we don't do anything with the return value anyways, and apply is async - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Comment: it seems initially the lastTimeRan would be -1 and minStartTime won't be less than or equal to -1 so  the preference also be never get updated , I think (lastTimeRan <= minStartTime) is the right way to do

Answer (score 1):

In order to do periodic task like executing a method daily the proper way to do it is using AlarmManager, it will trigger a broadcast according to your schedule configuration executing its onReceive method, this is the proper way to do this kind of schedule event task, see the following example to get a better idea about how to do it:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/2651

Regards!

Comment: I'm not sure this exactly answered the question, so I'll clarify what is going on and what is desired: There is an ad that runs in the onCreate, which is only supposed to be opened once a day, but the onCreate can be called up to many times per day. I don

Comment: hehe, even so the best way to do it is using alarms, just make a validation to be sure it was showed once during the day...