# How do I get an Android app to run a method daily?

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I need an ad screen(revmob) to show once daily when called from the onCreate method. I grabbed the idea from [How do I get an Android application's method to run a method daily with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438162/how-do-i-get-an-android-applications-method-to-run-a-method-daily-with-eclipse) but it is not working since the ad is loading every time the onCreate is called.

The code I have is:

```
if(runOnceDaily()){
    revmob = RevMob.start(this, REVMOB_APP_ID);
    revmob.showFullscreen(this);
}

private boolean runOnceDaily(){
    boolean result = false;
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
              "com.blogspot.blog.myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long minStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000*60*60*24;
    long lastTimeRan = prefs.getLong("lastTimeRan", -1);
    if (lastTimeRan >= minStartTime) {
        // a day passed.
        //also save the new 'lastTimeRan' in prefs
            result = true;
            prefs.edit().putLong("lastTimeRan", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to run a Method daily

Answer (score 0):

Use Alarmmanager with BroadcastReceiver class. 
Call your method which needs to be run everyday in the OnReceive method of receiver. 
This method would be very easy.